# Почему Android Studio не принимает картинки?

Tags: android-studio, android

Подскажите, почему android studio не загружает картинки в папку drawable никакого формата?

Появляется ошибка:

```
Refactoring cannot be performed   
File C:\Users....\cat.png is read-only
```

Comment: В Android Studio, на папке drawable нажми на правую кнопку и в выпадающем списке выбери папку drawable. Откроется папка ресурсов, закинь туда картинки и потом в IDE, на той же папке drawable выбери опцию Synchronize 'drawable'.

Comment: Может быть, надо запускать ее от имени администратора?

Comment: @metalurgus сомнительно) у меня та же фигня, но студия запускается со всеми правами, приходится добавлять в папку и синхронить.

Comment: How to Upload Image using Android Studio [Drawable Folder] in 5 minutes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VX8TW1fitcs

Answer (score 2):

В нижней части студии стоит блокировка на изменения файлов в проекте. 
[image]

Нужно нажать на иконку замочка.

**UPD**
ответ из комментария:

Файл должен находится в директории текущего пользователя.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/cqFKi30.png не уверен. Все норм, может из-за русских букв в пути, но уже и это проверил...

Comment: Сам файл находится в директории текущего пользователя?

Comment: Спасибо огромное, целый месяц с этим мучался.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что файл доступен только для чтения, а, при перетаскивании в студию, Вы его перемещаете. Скопируйте его комбинацией Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V и будет Вам счастье.

Answer (score -2):

У меня была такая же проблема, решил с помощью изменения структуры с Android на Project

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?